# Android fragment transaction listener

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I need to listen when a fragment transaction is performed, for example, when I replace a fragment with another, without call to addToBackStack(). FragmentManager class provides a addOnBackStackChangedListener callback, but when I perform a fragment replacement without call to addToBackStack, it is not executed.

Edit: the listen operation is performed in a class which only have access to the activity instance and its fragment manager.

Comment: for what purposes you need this?

Comment: For a library which performs some actions when a fragment is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Base class for all your fragments. Then you can override onDetach() method. For example

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onDetach() {
   // run code that needed by your library. e.g.
    if (getActivity() != null && getActivity() instanceof MainActivity) {
    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).someMethodToDetectOnDetach();
    }
    super.onDetach();
}
```

And then extends your fragments from BaseFragment like this

```
public class MyFragment extends BaseFragment {
// .....
}
```

Comment: The same behavior you can use in onAttach(Context context); method (maybe is will be even better)

Comment: Yes, I could do that, but I'm building a library project and I don't want to force that kind of things, like using a base class. But I think there is no other ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Fragment's onAttach() method.

Comment: The listen operation for fragment transactions is performed in a class which only have access to an activity instance and its FragmentManager. I  will edit my question to clarify.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have just tried an onBackStackChange listener but it never gets called even after setting it with the FragmentManager.