# Events triggered in FragmentA when FragmentB is popped in android fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

**What I have**

1. I have a Activity `MainActivity.java`
2. I have Added a Fragment FragmentA to `MainActivity.java`
3. Then I Add another `FragmentB` to `MainActivity.java`
4. Now When I pop the `FragmentB` I land Into `FragmentA`

---

**What I am trying to know**

- I want to know which event in `FragmentA` is triggered
- I want to trigger an event in `FragmentA` when I pop `FragmentB`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/39975529/2661303

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this is to use RxBus library https://github.com/Anadea/RxBus. Use Rxbus.subscribe in FargmentA and RxBus.publish inside andother fragment

Comment: This is a valid solution since this can be achieved as proposed. But I ended up not using `RxJava` but a similar one called `EventBus` :)

Comment: sure, dude (y) glad to help